# Large Object disappears when behind another smaller object Opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am trying to draw a large polygon behind the cube to appear like the floor. How ever when ever the background floor is behind the cube it disappears completely. Here is the display function including the background I want to add and one of the cubes sides.

```
void display(){
//  Clear screen and Z-buffer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


// Reset transformations
 glLoadIdentity();


 //background floor
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);   
  glColor3f(   0.5,  0.5, 0.5);
 glVertex3f(  1, -0.9, 1 );  // x-y-z right bottom  
 glVertex3f(  0.6,  0.5, 1 );      //right top
 glVertex3f( -0.6,  0.5, 1 );    //left top
 glVertex3f( -1, -0.9, 1 ); //left bottom
  glEnd();
 // Rotate when user changes rotate_x and rotate_y
 glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );



  // FRONT side of cube
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.5, 0.0 );
  glVertex3f(  0.05, -0.05, -0.05 );    
  glVertex3f(  0.05,  0.05, -0.05 );      
  glVertex3f( -0.05,  0.05, -0.05 );      
  glVertex3f( -0.05, -0.05, -0.05 );      
 //I have omitted the other 5 sides 
  glEnd();
  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

Comment: Some screenshots would be illustrative.

Comment: Not much to go on - but I'd suggest `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`

Comment: I couldn't add snapshots because its my first time on stack overflow. 
@BrettHale I tried the glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) however the object in the back disappears when behind the cube

Comment: It looks like your floor is in the direction. Have you checked the view frustum?

Comment: 1 hour and no one bitched about deprecation yet, I'm amazed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your poligon is facing outwards.
Try disabling backface culling with `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`. If this works swap the order of the vertices (should be CCW or trigonometric, on the side that the polygon should be visible from).

Don't leave the face culling disabled, unless you don't care about performance.